# ISQL For each author, list their number, last name, and number of books they written

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.author_num, a.author_last, COUNT(w.book_code)
FROM book.book b, book.author a, book.wrote w
WHERE (b.book_code=w.book_code and w.author_num=a.author_num)
ORDER BY a.author_last DESC;
```

I have 3 tables; book, author, and wrote.  I need to find how many books that author has written. Do I need a sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT a.author_num, a.author_last, COUNT(w.book_code)
FROM book.book b, book.author a, book.wrote w
WHERE (b.book_code=w.book_code and w.author_num=a.author_num)
GROUP BY a.author_num, a.author_last
ORDER BY a.author_last DESC;
```

Although I feel like your column names aren't quite correct

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Turns out I tried using group by but I put it after ORDER BY..silly me ._.